# Matlab: Summation over Array Dimensions

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array, sum

I've done quite a bit of searching and haven't been able to find a satisfactory answer so far, so I'm sorry if this question has already been raised.

I'm stuck on how to sum over the dimensions of an array. I have array A(w0,lambda,2048,2048), and I would like to be able to define a second array U(w0, 2048, 2048) which is composed of the sum of A over dimension lambda.

So far I have been defining both A and U as follows:

```
A = zeros(length(w0),length(lambda),2048,2048);
U = zeros(length(w0),2048,2048);
for ii = 1:length(w0)                    % Scan through spot sizes
    for aa = 1:length(lambda)            % Scan through wavelengths
          A(ii,aa,:,:) = ASM(w0(ii),lambda(aa),z1,z2);
    end
    U(ii,:,:) = sum(A,2);
end
```

Where ASM is just a function. z1 and z2 are defined earlier, and not relevant here.

I have been trying to come up with other possible ways of finding U(w0,2048,2048) as the sum over the second dimension of A (lambda), but haven't been successful...

Thanks for any pointers, and sorry again if this has already been resolved!

James.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the sounds of it, you just want:

```
U = squeeze(sum(A, 2));
```

[`squeeze()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/squeeze.html) eliminates singleton dimensions.

Here are two alternative solutions:

```
U = reshape(sum(A, 2), [length(w0) 2048 2048]);
```

or:

```
U = sum(A, 2);
U = U(:, 1, :, :);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Got it working now with the first option. Hadn't come across the squeeze() function before now -- pretty new to matlab.

Answer (score 0):

Try using '[sum](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html)' function with a dimension argument, and collapse result on the desired dimensions.

```
z = rand(2,3,2,2);
q = sum(z,2); %sum all 3 matrices of size 2x2x2 to get 2x1x2x2 result
zz = q(:,1,:,:); %zz is now 2x2x2, by collapsing the dimension 2.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to answer! Always good to have as many ways as possible to do these things. I went for the first option from Oli Charlesworth, though -- Slightly less code.